# cargar datos de usuario al iniciar sesión - react-native

Tags: react-native

Tengo una app donde puedo iniciar sesión y si el usuario y contraseña es correcta me envía a mi screen, pero necesito que me cargue los datos del usuario que inicio sesión y no logro hacerlo siempre me aparece “undefined”.

Para este inicio de sesión tengo un AuthContext.tsx donde tengo   una constante “signIn” donde se verifica que el usuario y la contraseña es correcta y me envía a mi screen además de crear el token sin problemas, pero también tengo otra constante que se llama “checkToken” que se supone que tiene que verificar el token y traerme los datos del usuario de la API para posteriormente utilizarlos, pero no lo hace.

La Api que utilizo esta en .php y funciona correctamente ya que la utilizo con un proyecto de react.js y funciona bien pero en react-native no he podido que me cargue la dos datos del usuario al iniciar sesión.

Código completo con Api : https://github.com/Giovannychvz/login

AutContext.tsx

```
        import React,{ createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
        import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

        import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

        import cafeApi from "../api/cafeApi";
        import { LoginData, LoginResponse, RegisterData, Usuarios } from "../interfaces/appinterfaces";
        import { authReducer, AuthState } from "./AuthReducer";

        type AuthContextProps = {
            errorMessage: string;
            token: string | null;
            user: Usuarios | null;
            status: 'checking' | 'authenticated' | 'not-authenticated';
            signUp: (RegisterData: RegisterData) => void;
            signIn: (loginData : LoginData) => void;
            logOut: () => void;
            removeError: () => void;

        }

       const authInicialState: AuthState = {
            status:'checking',
            token: null,
            user: null,
            errorMessage:''
        }

        export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextProps);
        export const AuthProvider = ({children}: any) =>{

            const[state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer,authInicialState);

            useEffect(() =>{
                checkToken();
            }, [])

            const checkToken = async () =>{
               const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');

               //No token, no autenticado
               if (!token) return dispatch({ type:'notAuthenticated'});
            
               //hay token
               const resp = await cafeApi.get('/usuarios/user-info.php');

               if(resp.status !== 200){
                  return dispatch({type:'notAuthenticated'});
               }

               await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', resp.data.token)       

               dispatch({
                   type: 'signUp',
                   payload:{
                       token: resp.data.token,
                       user: resp.data.usuarios
                   }
               })

            }

           const signIn = async({correo, password}: LoginData) => {
               
                try {

             await fetch('https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero/usuarios/login.php',
            {
              method:'POST',
              headers:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'content-Type': 'application/json'
         
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({"email":correo, "password" : password})
            }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(resData => {
               if(resData.message == "Ha iniciado sesión correctamente.") {    

                dispatch({
                    type: 'signUp',
                    payload: {
                        //el token carga sin problemas
                        token: resData.token,
                        user: resData.usuarios
                    }
                    
                }); 
                        
               }else{
                Alert.alert(resData.message)
               }
               
            });
                   }catch (error) {
                    dispatch({type: 'addError',
                    payload: error.response.data.msg || 'Información incorrecta'})
                   }
            };

            

            return(
                <AuthContext.Provider value={{
                    ...state,           
                    signIn,        
                    removeError,
                }}>
                   {children}
                </AuthContext.Provider>
            )

        }
```

cafeApi.tsx

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

    const baseURL = 'https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero';

    const cafeApi = axios.create({baseURL});

    cafeApi.interceptors.request.use(

       async(config) =>{
         const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
         if (token){
             config.headers['x-token'] = token;

         }
         return config;
       } 
    );

    export default cafeApi;
```

Screen.tsx

```
    import { StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack'
    import React, { useContext } from 'react'
    import { Button, Image, Keyboard, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
    import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext'
    import { useForm } from '../hooks/useForm'


    interface Props extends StackScreenProps<any, any>{}

    export const ProtectedScreen = ({navigation}: Props) => {

      const {user, token} = useContext(AuthContext);

      return (
        <>
            <View>
                 
              <Text>
             //AQUI DEBERIA CARGAR LOS DATOS DEL USUARIO PERO NO CARGA NADA
                    {JSON.stringify( user, null, 5) }
                </Text>
      </View>

        

        </>
      )
    }
```

Encontré un solución a medias, cuando inicio sesión me carga los datos de perfil del usuario pero otras veces no, debe tener algún detalle que esta generando el conflicto.

en si lo que hice fue modificar mi "checkToken", por si alguien me puede colaborar ya casi la tengo.

AuthContext.tsx

```js
import React,{ createContext, useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

import cafeApi from "../api/cafeApi";
import { LoginData, LoginResponse, RegisterData, Usuarios } from "../interfaces/appinterfaces";
import { authReducer, AuthState } from "./AuthReducer";

type AuthContextProps = {
    errorMessage: string;
    token: string | null;
    user: Usuarios | null;
    status: 'checking' | 'authenticated' | 'not-authenticated';
    signUp: (RegisterData: RegisterData) => void;
    signIn: (loginData : LoginData) => void;
    checkToken: () => void;
    logOut: () => void;
    removeError: () => void;

}

const authInicialState: AuthState = {
    status:'checking',
    token: null,
    user: null,
    errorMessage:''


}


export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextProps);
export const AuthProvider = ({children}: any) =>{

    const [theUser, setUser] = useState(null);
    const[state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer,authInicialState);

    
    
   const signIn = async({correo, password}: LoginData) => {
      
        try {
          const res = await fetch('https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero/usuarios/login.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email: correo, password: password }),
          });
          const resData = await res.json();
      
          if (resData.message == 'Ha iniciado sesión correctamente.') {
            // Guardar el token en AsyncStorage
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', resData.token);
          console.log(JSON.stringify({theUser}) + "PERFIL");
            dispatch({
              type: 'signUp',
              payload: {
                token: resData.token,
                user: resData.usuarios,
              },
            });
          } else {
            Alert.alert(resData.message);
          }
          //console.log(resData)
        } catch (error) {
          dispatch({
            type: 'addError',
            payload: error.response?.data?.msg || 'Información incorrecta',
          });
        }
      };

  

    const checkToken = async () =>{
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
 
        cafeApi.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+token;
        
        if(token){
         const {data} = await cafeApi.get('/usuarios/user-info.php');
         if(data.success && data.user){
             setUser(data.user);
             //console.log(JSON.stringify({theUser}) + "aquifue");
             return;
         }
         setUser(null);
     }
       
        //No token, no autenticado
        if (!token) return dispatch({ type:'notAuthenticated'});
    
     }
 
 
     useEffect(() => {
         async function asyncCall(){
             await checkToken();
         }
         asyncCall();
     },[]);
     

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{
            ...state,
            signIn,
            removeError,
           // user:theUser,
            checkToken,
        }}>
           {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

//funcionando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//sin funcionar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No conozco mucho de React pero parece que checkToken sobreescribe los datos en el AsyncStorage, tal vez usando un try catch funcione.

Comment: pero como seria por lo que intentado y sigo con el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto, si te funciona te hago una explicación más detallada. Ahora no tengo mucho tiempo. Pero básicamente creo que en la función checkToken, cuando llamas a AsyncStorage.getItem('token'), siempre te devuelve null, lo que significa que el usuario no está autenticado.

```
const signIn = async ({ correo, password }: LoginData) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero/usuarios/login.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email: correo, password: password }),
    });
    const resData = await res.json();

    if (resData.message == 'Ha iniciado sesión correctamente.') {
      // Guardar el token en AsyncStorage
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', resData.token);

      dispatch({
        type: 'signUp',
        payload: {
          token: resData.token,
          user: resData.usuarios,
        },
      });
    } else {
      Alert.alert(resData.message);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'addError',
      payload: error.response?.data?.msg || 'Información incorrecta',
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: buen dia, no me funciona sigue igual null, agregue mi context que utilizo en reactjs donde me funciona sin problemas el login y traer los datos del usuario, no se si con este ejemplo me puedas ayudar ya que es muy similar a reactnative pero no he podido adaptarlo

Comment: Revisar [answer]

Comment: La verdad Giovanny es que no se, a ver si alguien puede ayudarte. Lo siento, suerte.

Comment: es que el problema debe estar en la funcion "checkToken" ya que al autenticar en el login debe traer los datos del usuario de user-info.php y no lo esta haciendo por eso la función "signIn" al verificar en login.php solo verifica si los accesos son correctos y  genera el token e inicia sesión pero no haca nada mas, no se como solucionarlo.

Comment: Encontré un solución a medias, cuando inicio sesión me carga los datos de perfil del usuario pero otras veces no, debe tener algún detalle que esta generando el conflicto. Sube en la pregunta la modificación

Answer (score 0):

logre solucionar el tema de los perfiles de cada usuario, agregue en el `useEffect` de la `checktoken` la función `signIn` ya al cargar el js no alcanzaba a cargar la información del usuario y por eso siempre aparecía `null` ya ahora cada vez que inicio sesión carga los datos y llama ala función checktoken pasandole la información:

```js
import React,{ createContext, useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

import cafeApi from "../api/cafeApi";
import { LoginData, LoginResponse, RegisterData, Usuarios } from "../interfaces/appinterfaces";
import { authReducer, AuthState } from "./AuthReducer";

type AuthContextProps = {
    errorMessage: string;
    token: string | null;
    user: Usuarios | null;
    status: 'checking' | 'authenticated' | 'not-authenticated';
    signUp: (RegisterData: RegisterData) => void;
    signIn: (loginData : LoginData) => void;
    checkToken: () => void;
    logOut: () => void;
    removeError: () => void;

}

const authInicialState: AuthState = {
    status:'checking',
    token: null,
    user: null,
    errorMessage:''


}

export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextProps);

export const AuthProvider = ({children}: any) =>{

    const [theUser, setUser] = useState(null);

    const[state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer,authInicialState);   
  
   const signIn = async({correo, password}: LoginData) => {
       
       try {
        const res = await fetch('https://webcom.com/apiTuparcero/usuarios/login.php', {
         // const res = await fetch('https://alira.ai-od.com/apiAlira/usuarios/login.php', {
         
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
         
           body: JSON.stringify({ email: correo, password: password }),
          });
          const resData = await res.json();
      
          if (resData.message == 'Ha iniciado sesión correctamente.') {
             await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', resData.token);
                  dispatch({
              type: 'signUp',
              payload: {
                token: resData.token,
                user: resData.usuarios,
              },
            });
          } else {
            Alert.alert(resData.message);
          }
          //console.log(resData)
        } catch (error) {
          dispatch({
            type: 'addError',
            payload: error.response?.data?.msg || 'Información incorrecta',
          });
        }
      };

     const checkToken = async () =>{
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
 
        cafeApi.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+token;
        
        if(token){
        const {data} = await cafeApi.get('/usuarios/user-info.php');
               if(data.success && data.user){
             setUser(data.user);
           console.log(data.user.name + " base de datos_check");
             return;
         }
         setUser(null);
     }
       
        //No token, no autenticado
        if (!token) return dispatch({ type:'notAuthenticated'});
     
             
 
     }
 
 
  useEffect(() => {
         async function asyncCall(){
             await checkToken();
         }
         asyncCall();
     },[signIn]);

   
   
    const removeError = () => {

     dispatch({type: 'removeError'});

    };

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{
            ...state,
            signUp,
            signIn,
            logOut,
            removeError,
            user:theUser,
            checkToken,
        }}>
           {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

}
```